# Assign values to an array partially in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have an array in VHDL of the form,

```
type CacheArray is array(0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(33 downto 0);
signal cache_array: CacheArray := (others => (others => '0'));
```

I wish to assign values to this array such that only one bit of each index is initialized. I suspected something like this will work,

```
cache_array(15 downto 0)(33) <= (others => '0');
```

But it gives the following error :-

```
Cache.vhd:72:16: direction of the range mismatch
Cache.vhd:72:30: static constant violates bounds
Cache.vhd:72:37: can't match character literal '0' with type array type "std_logic_vector"
```

In some sense, this is like a 2D matrix and I wish to initialize just one column completely.
What can be done besides assigning the bits one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving the first and second errors because your type is declared:

```
array(0 to 15)
```

but your assignment to the signal which instances this type is using:

```
cache_array(15 downto 0)
```

You should choose either `to` or `downto` for both.

The last error is because you are assigning `(others => '0')`, which is only applicable to vectors of bits, to a single bit. If you want to make that particular bit `'0'`, just assign it to `'0'`.

More generally, the syntax `cache_array(15 downto 0)(33)` is not meaningful.

---

If, per your comment and updated question, you want to assign one particular bit in every array element, you will have to use a loop of some kind:

Inside a process:

```
for i in cache_array'range loop
  cache_array(i)(33) <= '0';
end loop;
```

Outside a process as a concurrent assignment:

```
GenerateLabel : for i in cache_array'range generate
  cache_array(i)(33) <= '0';
end generate;
```

---

Note also that if you implement assignment of only one bit, the tools are unlikely to infer use of a block memory element for this functionality.

Comment: I want to make that particular bit `'0'` for all indices of the array. I tried this `comparisons(15 downto 0)(32) <= '0';` but I get an error `Cache.vhd:65:28: static constant violates bounds`.

Comment: @KalpeshKrishna OK, I was just trying to explain why your code was causing errors. Please see my edit.

Comment: I didn't know about these `generate` statements. All this does produce synthesizable code right? This looks really useful!

Comment: @KalpeshKrishna Yes, loops and generate statements are synthesizable. Note that both of these sorts of loops are unrolled, so the loop bounds must be known at synthesis time.

Comment: Also, do these happen in parallel in hardware? Or do they work in a sequential combinational manner?

Comment: @KalpeshKrishna You can implement sequential actions with `for` loops, but not for synthesizable code, for which, per my comment, the loop will always be unrolled (resulting in 'parallel' functionality). `generate` always describes 'parallel' functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Caution should be used in the generate loop method scary_jeff shows. concurrent statement in the generate loop will result in a separate process with a separate driver in each generated block, meaning you can't assign (33) for cache_array(i) from another process without resolving to a meta value.

The generate loop method is not generally useful without describing your entire cache operation in a single process.

There's also a third method using AND masking familiar to those with a programming background used to set cache_array(i)(33) to '0':

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cache is
end entity;

architecture foo of cache is
    type CacheArray is array(0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(33 downto 0);
    signal cache_array: CacheArray := (others => (others => '1'));

    constant MASK33:   CacheArray := (others => (33 => '0', others => '1'));

    function "and" (l,r: CacheArray) return CacheArray is
        variable retval: CacheArray;
    begin
        for i in l'range loop
            retval(i) := l(i) and r(i);
        end loop;
        return retval;
    end function;

    function to_string (arg: CacheArray) return string is
        variable retval: string (1 to CacheArray'length * 36);
        variable retptr: natural range 1 to CacheArray'length * 36;
    begin
        retptr := 1;
        for i in arg'range loop
            for j in arg(i)'range loop
                if j = arg(i)'left then
                    retval(retptr) := LF;
                    retptr := retptr + 1;
                    retval(retptr) := HT;
                    retptr := retptr + 1;
                end if;
                retval(retptr) := 
                        character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(arg(i)(j)));
                        if retptr < retval'length then
                            retptr := retptr + 1;
                        end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return retval;
    end function;

begin

-- GenerateLabel:
--     for i in cache_array'range generate
--         cache_array(i)(33) <= '0';
--     end generate;
--
-- Clear_33:
--     process (cache_array)
--     begin
--         for i in cache_array'range loop
--           cache_array(i)(33) <= '0';
--         end loop;
--     end process;
MASK:
    process (cache_array)
    begin
        cache_array <= cache_array and MASK33;
    end process;
SHOW:
    process (cache_array)
    begin
        report "cache_array = " & to_string(cache_array);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Because it required defining an "and" operator for type CacheArray, it lead to producing a to_string function for type CacheArray as well, which can tell us the contents of your cache:

```
ghdl -r cache
cache.vhdl:67:9:@0ms:(report note): cache_array =
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
    1111111111111111111111111111111111
cache.vhdl:67:9:@0ms:(report note): cache_array =
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
    0111111111111111111111111111111111
```

The first cache value is the initial value, the second is the result of the "and" mask (note I initially filled cache_array with '1's to show the "and" worked).

You could add additional field separators for your cache word to make it easier to read and along with things like specific radix usage, noting you're responsible for calculating the retval string length properly and managing the retval pointer (retptr) in the to_string function. You could go as far as to add an output header. You could also organize output on a cache line basis. ...

In addition to report statements textio can be used to allow finer control of output and redirection to a text file. Either can allow you to observe cache state without resorting to reading waveform displays.